# Android - The API key can only be specified once <meta-data> duplicates

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I’m trying to add Google map in to may app, so I have taken the API key. Unfortunately when I inserted the API key in manifest.xml through a meta-data tag, it automatically inserted another meta-data tag at compile time as shown below. Now it generates below mentioned error. The worst case is, even I delete each of them or both, it automatically generates both tags at compile time again and throws the error.

Any help?

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exampl.t_collect/com.exampl.t_collect.activity.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
.........
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
..........
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ad.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
```

**Manifast.xml meta tags**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exampl.t_collect"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<!--
 To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
 option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

```
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Dash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Collection"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_collection" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Collection1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_collection" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Collection2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_collection" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Advance"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_advance" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Customer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_customer" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Data_store"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_data_store" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.DataRqeuset"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_data_rqeuset" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.Settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.PastData_activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_past_data" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.util.UploadGPS" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.findTrucks"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_find_trucks" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSy*********************************" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.exampl.t_collect.activity.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
        android:value="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.EnableWalletOptimizationReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.ENABLE_WALLET_OPTIMIZATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you show us the entire manifest file?

Comment: Try and remove `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` this meta data tag from your manifest. I don't know why its getting regenerated. Are you editing the correct manifest file? `(app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)`

Comment: yes. OMG just now i noticed. in the manifast there is an activity tag for `com.exampl.t_collect.activity.MapsActivity` which is also auto generating.

Comment: Actually i added a google map activity to my project previously and removed. i think this tag should relevant to that activity.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Delete your `"com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"` meta-data entry.

The `"com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"` entry is sufficient for both the Maps and Places services.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7824

---

EDIT - Google updated their documents to explicitly call this out now:

1. https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#api-key
2. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup#use-key

Comment: this is perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the Below Version it will resolve this issue.

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
```