# Google Maps which extends Base Activity can't inflate map fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, layout-inflater, appcompatactivity

I believe it is possible to setContentView() to a map fragment while extending AppCompatActivity. However I need to extend a Base Activity which extends AppCompatActivity. This means that I need to inflate my map fragment with a container. 
Unfortunately it throws this exception every time:

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Class is not a View com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Do I have to choose or is there a way to work around this problem?

I am creating an app that needs to access a map while still keep certain functions like the navigation drawer hence I have a Base Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provided code I am just guessing here, but from the error you posted you are probably doing this in your XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

SupportMapFragment isn't a view, it is fragment, so you should place it using the fragment tag, as following:

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get thrown with this error: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment. I never know about adding in a class view like this but I have an idea the problem lies with the inflater.

Comment: This would work if you extend Fragment activity class, I am try to find a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still has this problem after migrating to SDK v28, here's something that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798398/4483494

Essentially, if you have already defined in your application manifest the key "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY", you should delete the key "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY".